# Program's icon showing twice on taskbar. It's not doubly installed. How can I just have the one?

Tags: ubuntu, icons, ubuntu-18.04

I downloaded and installed Firefox Developer Edition, for which I made an executable desktop icon. I moved it to `~/.local/share/applications`, and this is what it reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/name/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Icon[en_US]=/home/name/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Name[en_US]=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/home/name/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev/firefox
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
```

I have added the icon to Favorites, so it appears at the head of the icons, yet when I click on it, another icon appears at the end of said list. If I click on it more, this newer icon gets the orange dot(s) to specify that there are multiple windows. When I right-click on those icons, I just get "All Windows" and "Quit", whereas when I right-click on the original I get "New Window", "Remove From Favorites" and "Show Details".

How may I get just the one icon that gets the indicators like in the second icon described above, yet with all of the right-click options?

Thank you.

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/a/1447066/173227

Answer (score 3):

Received the answer from another forum:

1. Launch the application
2. Fire up a Terminal and run `xprop WM_CLASS`.
3. Click the application window. You'll get some output like `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Navigator", "Firefox Developer Edition"`. Choose one of the classes, eg `Firefox Developer Edition` in this example.
4. Add the class as the value of `StartupWMClass` in the .desktop file. For example, `StartupWMClass=Firefox`
5. Save the .desktop file, close the application and re-open it. There should now obly be 1 icon in the launcher.